# Routing in Net Core 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-5

I have an  application developed using C# under Net 5. The issue I am facing is only happening when I access the site remotely as it is already published on IIS, otherwise running it directly from Visual Studio seems to work rather fine.

Below is my "Index" View :

```html
<form method="post" asp-action="GenerateOTP" asp-controller="Home">
```

Below is the controller:

```cs
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GenerateOTP(OTPData mydata)
{
    ...
    return RedirectToAction("EnterOTP", "Home");
}
```

Basically the app should automatically redirect to the page "EnterOTP" after performing the commands on the "GenerateOTP" method. Instead on production the page redirects to Home/GenerateOTP on the browser and this would definitely not work as the page doesn't exist.

Any recommendation on what I am missing.

Comment: Could it be that an error occurs when `GenerateOTP()` runs and never reaches `return RedirectToAction("EnterOTP", "Home");`?

Comment: @TasosK. What bother me the most is that if I run from Visual studio when debugging, It works pretty fine but once  published, It doesn't.

Comment: What he means is; have you used browser inspection tools to confirm the 302 response headers, and if the redirect has started and/or failed.

Comment: It fails to redirect and returns a 502

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos There isn't a single 302 that is returned. There was a block on the first POST.

Comment: This has nothing to do with `RedirectToAction` then. Either the proxy/firewall didn't like what it saw, or the method threw and never responded to the proxy. Add logging to your method to see whether there were any errors before reaching `RedirectToAction`. Check the IIS request logs to see if the POST made it to the server at all

Comment: You want to check your BaseURI? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/182587/best-practice-to-configure-baseaddress-uri-in-mvc.html

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos :-D Quite interesting, I just got rid of `await _context.SaveChangesAsync();` and the redirection works just fine. Gets me wondering of alternative means to save changes.

Comment: @Nickson there's nothing wrong with SaveChangesAsync. If your action throws, you need to find out what's wrong. At the vey least add logging to log any exceptions. You still haven't posted your code so it's impossible to say what's wrong

Comment: You're saying that it bothers you that the issue happens in production but not locally. That makes me think that you assume that when things work locally that means they should work in production. That's a dangerous assumption, and you should disabuse yourself of that notion. Local and Production are different, so things may not work in production that work locally and vice versa. It's up to you to add sufficient logging to your application so that when things go wrong, you can find out what happened. And to code defensively so that when things go wrong, they go wrong gracefully.

Answer (score 0):

@PanagiotisKanavos Thanks for the tip. Checked my `Event Viewer` and found out the issue was on my ApplicationPool Identity. It wasn't authorized  access to that directory. Changed it from `ApplicationPoolIdentity` to `LocalSystem` and all works fine right now.